# GET variable after doing a Join Query

Tags: php

For the code below, on the second link (`http://www...com/sandbox/comments/index.php?submission='.$row["title"].'`), I would like to pass $row["submissionid"], on as a GET variable.  I tried this and it caused all of the code below to produce a blank result.  Is there a way that I can do I want?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT 
                s.loginid
                ,s.title
                ,s.url
                ,s.displayurl
                ,l.username
                ,COUNT(c.commentid) countComments
             FROM 
                 submission s
            INNER
             JOIN
                 login l
               ON
                s.loginid = l.loginid
             LEFT OUTER
             JOIN
                 comment c
                ON
                 s.submissionid = c.submissionid
             GROUP
                BY
                 s.submissionid
             ORDER  
                BY 
                 s.datesubmitted DESC
             LIMIT 
                 10";           

$result = mysql_query($sqlStr);

$arr = array(); 
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec\">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename1"><a href="http://www.'.$row["url"].'">'.$row["title"].'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="sitename2"><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/members/index.php?profile='.$row["username"].'">'.$row["username"].'</a><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/comments/index.php?submission='.$row["title"].'">'.$row["countComments"].'</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: That code shouldn't produce a blank result (at least the empty table should be there) unless there's an error. Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: The code works right now.  It produces a blank result when I add &submissionid='.$row["submissionid"].' to the URL where I want to pass along the additional GET variable.

Comment: Could you revise your post and put in the code that doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Add submissionid to your select.

Comment: s.submissionid or c.submissionid?

Comment: I thought I tried this before... but I tried it again after you suggested it, using s.submissionid in the SELECT, and now for some reason it works.  Go figure.

Comment: They will be the same, it doesn't matter which you choose, although s seems to make more sense based on what you already have.